# Mathematica package for supergravity and superstring theory

Tags: tensors, differentials

I am looking for a Mathematica package that can manipulate tensors for supergravity, string theory or M-theory. I am particularly looking for a package that can do spinor and Clifford algebra computations. Also, I would like this package to be able to do wedge and hodge dual, and other computation relating to forms. Can anyone suggest a specific one? I looked for atlas2, but it seems I have to pay to use it without a trial version.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no package that can do spinor computations in arbitrary dimensions. There is [Gamma](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0105086) but that 'only' does gamma matrix computations.

As for exterior forms, Mathematica 9 can do a bit of that: see e.g. [`TensorWedge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorWedge.html) and [`HodgeDual`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HodgeDual.html). You might also want to look at the [xTerior package](http://xact.es/xTerior/index.html) for xAct.

Speaking of xAct, its author maintains a fairly exhaustive list of tensor algebra software [here](http://xact.es/links.html).